# Sum List<Map> to get distinct list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List<Map>` that I need the IDs to be distinct in the list and obtain a cumulative value for each ID.

What I currently have works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

My code:

```
List tagId = ['a', 'b'];
List oldList = [{'id': 'a', 'value': 1}, 
                {'id': 'a', 'value': 1}, 
                {'id': 'a', 'value': 1}, 
                {'id': 'a', 'value': 1},
                {'id': 'b', 'value': 1},
                {'id': 'b', 'value': 1}];
List newList = [];
  
  for(final i in tagId) {
    int totalValue = 0;
    for(final d in oldList){
      if(i == d['id']){
        totalValue++;
      }
    }
    newList.add({'id': i, 'value': totalValue});
  }
  print(newList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wrote the `tagList` manually, you don't want to do that manually or from another unnecessary algorithm that will result in it.

If you need just access to the `id` and `value`, then you probably want to avoid an `O(N^2)` algorithm, I wrote an `O(N)` that might help for better performance:

```
  Map<String, int> map = {};
  for(int index = 0; index < oldList.length; index+=1) {
    map[oldList[index]["id"]] = (map[oldList[index]["id"]] ?? 0) + oldList[index]["value"] as int;
  }
  
  print(map); // {a: 4, b: 2}
```

and if you need the same result then you can just add this:

```
  List<Map> asMapList = [];
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    asMapList.add({"id": key, "value": value});
  } ); 
  print(asMapList); // [{id: a, value: 4}, {id: b, value: 2}]
```